# Question about the "utf-8"-behavior

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, encode

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Encode qw(encode);

no warnings qw(utf8);

my $c = "\x{ffff}";

my $utf_8 = encode( 'utf-8', $c );
my $utf8 = encode( 'utf8', $c );

say "utf-8 :  @{[ unpack '(B8)*', $utf_8 ]}";
say "utf8  :  @{[ unpack '(B8)*', $utf8 ]}";

# utf-8 :  11101111 10111111 10111101
# utf8  :  11101111 10111111 10111111
```

Does the "utf-8" encode this way, to fix my codepoint automaticaly to the last interchangeable codepoint (of the first plane)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [UTF-8 vs. utf8 vs. UTF8 section](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode#UTF-8_vs._utf8_vs._UTF8) of the  [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode) docs.

To summarize, Perl has two different UTF-8 encodings.  Its native encoding is called `utf8`, and basically allows any codepoint, regardless of what the Unicode standard says about that codepoint.

The other encoding is called `utf-8` (a.k.a. `utf-8-strict`).  This allows only codepoints that are assigned by the Unicode standard.

`\x{FFFF}` is not a valid codepoint according to Unicode.  But Perl's `utf8` encoding doesn't care about that.

By default, the `encode` function replaces any character that does not exist in the destination charset with a substitution character (see the [Handling Malformed Data section](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode#Handling_Malformed_Data)).  For `utf-8`, that substitution character is [U+FFFD (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), which is encoded in UTF-8 as 11101111 10111111 10111101 (binary).

Comment: It is **not true** that U+FFFF is not a valid code point according to Unicode.  Of course it is; it’s merely illegal for interchange. **These are *very* different things.** This bug has been fixed in recent evelopment releases, allowing `perl -wE 'say "\x{FFFF}" =~ /^.$/ || 0'` to produce 1 without nary a peep.